# find an element that has an attribute that has a specific value c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following Xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<session xmlns="http://winscp.net/schema/session/1.0" name="test" start="2014-04-04T15:54:09.728Z">
  <upload>
    <filename value="D:\ftp\test1.TXT" />
    <destination value="/in/test1.TXT" />
    <result success="true" />
  </upload>
  <touch>
    <filename value="/in/test1.TXT" />
    <modification value="2014-03-27T12:45:20.000Z" />
    <result success="true" />
  <upload>
    <filename value="D:\ftp\test2.TXT" />
    <destination value="/in/test2.TXT" />
    <result success="true" />
  </upload>
  <touch>
    <filename value="/in/test2.TXT" />
    <modification value="2014-03-27T12:45:20.000Z" />
    <result success="false" />
  </touch>
</session>
```

I need to and I'd like to browse all `filename` elements `where result success="true"` for both nodes `touch` and `upload` .

I will get only `D:\ftp\test1.TXT`

So this is my code :

```
string file =@"C:\\Program.xml";
            if (File.Exists(file))
            {
                try
                {
                    XElement root = XElement.Load(file);
                    IEnumerable<XElement> filename =
                        from el in root.Elements("upload")
                        where (string)el.Attribute("result success") == "true"
                        select el;
                    foreach (XElement el in filename)
                        Console.WriteLine(el);
                 }
              }
```

How can I modify the code above to get my purpose?

Comment: With your updated question I don't believe it is possible -- there is no relationship in the data between the "joined" touch and upload nodes.  Does the ordering matter.  Please update with requirements

Comment: @Hogan yes the order does matter . For the same filename , we have the touch and upload successively.

Comment: **FYI** - I added code using a `for` loop instead of Linq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the update:

```
void Main()
{
  XElement root = XElement.Parse (
  @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<session  name='test' start='2014-04-04T15:54:09.728Z'>
  <upload>
    <filename value='D:\ftp\test1.TXT' />
    <destination value='/in/test1.TXT' />
    <result success='true' />
  </upload>
  <touch>
    <filename value='/in/test1.TXT' />
    <modification value='2014-03-27T12:45:20.000Z' />
    <result success='true' />
  </touch>
  <upload>
    <filename value='D:\ftp\test2.TXT' />
    <destination value='/in/test2.TXT' />
    <result success='true' />
  </upload>
  <touch>
    <filename value='/in/test2.TXT' />
    <modification value='2014-03-27T12:45:20.000Z' />
    <result success='false' />
  </touch>
</session>");

  var upload = from el in root.Elements("upload") select el;
  var touch = from el in root.Elements("touch") select el;

  // use zip to join the two lists together based on ordering to a new object
  // this WON'T work if the lists are different lengths!
  var filename = upload.Zip(touch,(u,t) => new { upload = u, touch = t })
        .Where(item => item.upload.Descendants("result").First().Attribute("success").Value  == "true" 
                   &&  item.touch.Descendants("result").First().Attribute("success").Value  == "true")
        .Select(item => item.upload.Descendants("filename").First().Attribute("value").Value);


  foreach (string el in filename)
    Console.WriteLine(el);

}
```

NB, I took out the namespace on the XML content to make it clearer.  Feel free to put it back in.  (You will have to prefix your names with the namespace if you do.)

Also, I did this in Linq because it was asked for, I think it would be faster to use a for loop over the upload and touch arrays.

Here is how you would do that:

```
  var uploada = upload.ToArray();
  var toucha = touch.ToArray();
  List<string> filename = new List<string>();

  for(int index = 0; index < uploada.Length  ; index++)
  {
    if (uploada[index].Descendants("result").First().Attribute("success").Value  == "true" 
        && toucha[index].Descendants("result").First().Attribute("success").Value  == "true")
      filename.Add(uploada[index].Descendants("filename").First().Attribute("value").Value);
  }
```

---

This worked for me:

```
void Main()
{
  XElement root = XElement.Parse (
  @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<session  name=""test"" start=""2014-04-04T15:54:09.728Z"">
  <upload>
    <filename value=""D:\ftp\test1.TXT"" />
    <destination value=""/in/test1.TXT"" />
    <result success=""true"" />
  </upload>
  <touch>
    <filename value=""/in/test2.TXT"" />
    <modification value=""2014-03-27T12:45:20.000Z"" />
    <result success=""true"" />
  </touch>
</session>");

  var filename  = from el in root.Elements("upload")
                  where el.Descendants("result").First().Attribute("success").Value  == "true"
                  select el.Descendants("filename").First().Attribute("value").Value;


  Console.WriteLine(filename);

}
```

NB, I took out the namespace on the XML content to make it clearer.  Feel free to put it back in.  (You will have to prefix your names with the namespace if you do.)

Comment: What about touch node?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan - What about it? my first solution checks it.  The 2nd solution was a different question (see edit history on the question)

Comment: why did you change in the xml "" to '' ?

Comment: @user3456466 - it was easier to replace all `"` with `'` than to go to every `"` and make it `""`.  If you are reading from a file you don't need to do this-- it was just because it was a string literal in this example.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use XPath because it yields cleaner code.

```
var filenamesXPath = "/session/*[result[@success='true']]/filename";

var filenames = document.XPathSelectElements(filenamesXPath);
```

But this will not just work because of the missing namespace handling - what you actually need is the following.

```
var document = XDocument.Load(file);

var namespaces = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());

namespaces.AddNamespace("ns", document.Root.GetDefaultNamespace().NamespaceName);

var filenamesXPath = "/ns:session/*[ns:result[@success='true']]/ns:filename";

var filenames = document.XPathSelectElements(filenamesXPath, namespaces);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(file);
XNamespace ns = "http://winscp.net/schema/session/1.0";
var elements = doc.Descendants(ns + "upload")
                  .Where(e =>
                     (string)(e.Element(ns + "result")
                               .Attribute("success")) == "true");
```

**UPDATE**

Since requirements changed here is updated solution:

```
string xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<session xmlns='http://winscp.net/schema/session/1.0' name='test' start='2014-04-04T15:54:09.728Z'>
  <upload>
    <filename value='D:\ftp\test1.TXT' />
    <destination value='/in/test1.TXT' />
    <result success='true' />
  </upload>
  <touch>
    <filename value='/in/test1.TXT' />
    <modification value='2014-03-27T12:45:20.000Z' />
    <result success='true' />
  </touch>
  <upload>
    <filename value='D:\ftp\test2.TXT' />
    <destination value='/in/test2.TXT' />
    <result success='true' />
  </upload>
  <touch>
    <filename value='/in/test2.TXT' />
    <modification value='2014-03-27T12:45:20.000Z' />
    <result success='false' />
  </touch>
</session>";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XNamespace ns = "http://winscp.net/schema/session/1.0";
var fileNames = doc.Descendants(ns + "result")
    .Where(r => (string)r.Attribute("success") == "true")
    .Select(e => (string)e.ElementsBeforeSelf(ns + "filename").Single().Attribute("value"));
```

`Single` used for some scheme validation. In order, if there are no exact one `filename` in each node touch or upload node you will get exception.

Comment: OP updated his question, changed what he was looking for "filename elements where result success="true""

Answer (score 0):

```
var xe = XElement.Parse(xml);
var ns = xe.Name.Namespace;
var filenames = from d in xe.Elements()
                let success =  d.Element(ns + "result").Attribute("success")
                where success != null & success.Value == "true"
                select d.Element(ns + "filename").Attribute("value").Value;
filenames.Dump();
```

This should return you a list of filenames that have a result "true".

Comment: he needs both the upload and the touch to have success=true.

Comment: Right, noticed that he edited, but I missed that bit.